# Qt designer: QToolButton above image

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to display a window splitted in 2 to show 2 videos side by side.
I've created two QLabel in an horizontal_layout and will use setPixmap.

I want to put a 'parameter' button in the top-right of my window, if possible above my right picture. Is it possible to set this button above the right image?

Comment: Do you mean *overlayed*, or just in a position that is vertically above? In the first case, you cannot do that from Designer (layout managers don't allow it) and you can only add that by code; in the second, use a nested layout, create a vertical layout, add the button to it (by setting the proper alignment) and add a horizontal layout, to which you can add the labels. Alternatively, just use a grid layout.

Comment: Yes, I mean overlayed: so I can't do that in QT Designer. Thanks for your answer.